# multipilcation of float value by -1 in java

Tags: java, floating-point, multiplication

Why I am getting -0.0 when 0.0 multiplied by -1???
I have taken 0.0 as float

```
sign=-1;
float output=0.0;
JOptionPane.showmessagedialog(null,0.0*sign);
```

the output shown in -0.0 instead of 0

Comment: That appears to be the correct behavior to me.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: We should be getting 0.0 or 0 right?? why its coming as -0.0?

Comment: Nope.  You are experiencing the known, correct behavior of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: can i have the explanation for why floating point have such value? because in arithmetic 0.0 *-1 should be 0.0 rit?

Comment: -0.0 is the negative of 0.0.  Why shouldn't you get this value? The sign a separate bit.  This means that for every positive value there is a negative value. BTW 1/0.0 is positive infinity and 1/-0.0 is negative infinity.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Comment: "We should be getting 0.0 or 0 right??" -- Wrong. Who told you that? "why its coming as -0.0?" -- Because that's the right answer. "because in arithmetic 0.0 *-1 should be 0.0 rit?" -- In arithmetic, 0.0 equals -0.0, right? Anyway, you're talking about arithmetic on real numbers, but there are no real numbers in computers.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer taken from http://www.javawebtips.com/154041/

```
 "-0.0" Is produced when a floating-point operation results in a negative floating-point number so close to 0 that cannot be represented normally.

  -2.0 / Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY -> -0.0 

"-0.0" Is numerically identical to "0.0". However, some operations involving "-0.0" are different than the same operation with "0.0".

  (-0.0) == 0.0 -> true 
  2.0 / (0.0) - Infinity 
  2.0 / (-0.0) ->-Infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values have both positive and negative zero.  It may seem quirky, but there's a good reason for it (given the representational limits of floating point numbers).

You might consider casting your result to an `int` if you would really like the answer to just be `0`.

Comment: KKK..Thank you so much Mr.Gain

Answer (score 1):

The zeros in Java floating point do not just represent the real number zero. They are used to represent every number whose absolute magnitude is too small to be represented as a non-zero number, every underflow result.

Similarly, the infinities represent not just the result of division by zero, but every result whose absolute magnitude is too big to be represented as a finite number, every overflow result.

Making zero signed permits distinction between positive underflow results and negative underflow results, including, as already stated in another answer, getting the correct infinity on division of a non-zero number by an underflow result.